# Pool board question about trajectories of balls!

Tags: geometry, rectangles

> In this problem we are dealing with rectangular pool boards.
> Our boards have pointwise holes at the corners and nowhere else. A pointwise pool ball is running on the board and it never stops but falls down at a corner when it arrives there.
> If the ball starts its run at the left bottom corner at angle 45o to both of the adjacent sides of a 4×6 board then its path is shown below.
>
> (I.) To which corner the ball arrives?
> (II.) What is the total number of cushions until it falls down at the corner?
> (III.) What is the total length of its path? (Through how many 1×1 squares does it go through?)
>
> Try to answer these questions in the following cases:
> a) 3 × 5;
> b) 4 × 8;
> c) 15 × 18;
> d) 2021 × 235;
> e) 2021 × 900.
>
> f) Try to answer questions (I.) , (II.) , (III.) in the case of an m×n board
> in terms of m and n where m and n are positive integers.

I have got no idea how to solve any of these!

Would you mind telling me how I can begin to understand and solve this question?

#### Cheers!

Comment: Easy: draw a sketch for every size of billiard.

Comment: See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_billiards

Comment: thanks both of you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, more like a remark that may or may not be helpful.  It's a way of diagramming the problem.

Consider the case of a billiard table $6$ units long and $4$ units high.  In the following figure every point where the $45^{\circ}$ line crosses one of the dotted lines corresponds to a bounce off a cushion, so the ball bounces off $3$ cushions before dropping into a corner pocket.

[image: 4 by 6 billiard]

Comment: oh! so you can 'unfold' the table to get all of the sides!